# What would the ancient Romans have called Hercules' Club?

Tags: ancient-greek, roman-culture, mythology

During the 2nd to 3rd century, Romans would wear a pendant which we call a Hercules' Club, in much the same way a modern Christian would wear a crucifix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules%27_Club_(amulet) What would the Latin term for this pendant be? If there is an ancient Greek term for this pendant, I would be interested in learning that too. Would the term for the pendant be different from the term used to show Hercules' ownership of a club?

Comment: For others who hadn't heard of these, the Wikipedia article has a photo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules%27_Club_(amulet)

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure we have direct evidence of this particular pendant, but we do have what the Romans called the club and what they called pendants in general.

The club is called the *clava*. Varro (*LL* 8.26.6) mentions it when he's discussing Greek nouns in Latin:

> utrum Herculi an Herculis **clavam** dici oporteat
> whether we ought to say **club** of Herculus or club of Hercules

Tacitus also mentions that the Aestii wear a pendant of a boar to honor the Mother of the Gods.

> Matrem deum venerantur. Insigne superstitionis formas aprorum gestant
> The worship the Mother of the Gods. They wear the forms of boars as an emblem of this cult.

The pendant itself could be called different things, just as in English we could also say "amulet." But given Tacitus' language, it'd probably be simplest to say *insigne clavae Herculis* or *formam clavae Herculis*.

Comment: So could amuletum clavae Herculis be used if you wanted to highlight the religious aspect of the pendent? Insigne has more of a military badge aspect from the searches I've done.

Answer (score 10):

To add the Greek: the usual word for a club, including specifically Hercules' club, is [ῥόπαλον](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dr%28o%2Fpalon) *rhópalon*.

There are various words for a pendant or amulet, including [περίαμμα](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dperi%2Famma) *períamma* and [περίαπτον](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dperi%2Faptos) *períapton*, both meaning "(something) hung around". So a "a pendant of Hercules' club" could be something like περίαμμα Ἡρακλέους ῥοπάλου *períamma Hērakléous rhopálou*, though I don't know whether that particular phrase is attested anywhere.

Comment: Your answer was extremely helpful! It pointed me in a new directions, and I've come across the term panchálkeon (παγχάλκεον), which is either a bronze club or a club with bronze bands wrapped around it. Herakles is attributed with two different clubs, a wood one he made himself, and a bronze one gifted from Hephaistos. would Hērakléous panchálkeon (Ἡρακλέους παγχάλκεον) be accurate way to describe the gift from Hephaistos?

Comment: It appears I am mistaken. panchálkeon (παγχάλκεον) is an adjective meaning made of bronze. rópalon panchálkeon (ῥόπαλον παγχάλκεον) is a bronze club. So would Hērakléous rópalon panchálkeon (Ἡρακλέους ῥόπαλον παγχάλκεον) be correct?

Comment: @Walter παγχάλκεον means "all-bronze, completely bronze"; the normal word for "(made of) bronze" is χάλκεον or (in Attic) χαλκοῦν. So "the bronze club of Heracles" could be τὸ χαλκοῦν ῥόπαλον Ἡρακλέους, though other word orders are possible too.

Answer (score 4):

We have a few references to what the Romans called Hercules’ original club.  For instance, [line 625 of Seneca’s *Hercules Furens* says,

> agnosco toros umerosque et alto nobilem trunco manum.

Frank Justus Miller translates this as:

> Aye, now I recognize the bulging thews, the shoulders, the hand famed for its huge club.

Where *trunco* is the word translated *club.*

On line 466 of the same work, his club is called a *clava*.

In the *Aeneid*, we have at [Verg. A. 8.219](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Verg.+A.+8.219&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0055)

> Hic vero Alcidae furiis exarserat atro
> felle dolor: rapit arma manu nodisque gravatum
> robur et aerii cursu petit ardua montis.

[One translation of which is:](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/61596/61596-h/61596-h.htm)

> Black bile burned hot in Hercules; he grabbed
> His weapons, his great knotted club, went rushing
> Up to the mountain-top.

This translates [*robur*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=robur&la=la&can=robur0&prior=gravatum), literally hardwood or oak, as *club*, and *gravatum*, literally *heavy*, as *great.*  [Another translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0054%3Abook%3D8%3Acard%3D219) makes *nodisque gravatum robur* into “his club of knotted oak,” implicitly translating *gravatum* as *club* and *robur* as *of oak*.